# How to select class names with spaces and using wild card

Tags: jquery-selectors

In the below html snippet I am trying to create a JQuery Expression to select all a tags with class zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 Napa1-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_*"

I am confused about constructing the select syntax that contains spaces in the class name.  I also want a wild card at the end which is depicted above by the '*' char at the end.

```
<table class="Napa1-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_4" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
<a class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 Napa1-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3" style="border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-top-style: none; font-size: 1em; border-left-style: none;" href="/sites/Brand1/SubSite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the only 3 classes, and you're certain they will appear in that order, you could use a `attribute-starts-with` selector.

Try this:

```
$('a[class^=zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 Napa1-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_]')
```

This will select `<a>` elements where the `class` attribute starts with `zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 Napa1-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_`.

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Alternatively, you could get elements with the first two classes, and use a filter to make sure it ends with the third class. The way it is written, it assumes your "wildcard" character will be a number or numbers.

```
$('a.zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1.Napa1-topnav').filter(function() {
    return /zz1_TopNavigationMenu_\d+$/.test($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3):

the space character is not valid in a class name; it's a delimiter. A tag may contain multiple class names. For example, `<a id="foobar" class="foo bar">` has two classes: foo and bar, hence `$('#foobar').getClasses()` will have two class names.

So, if you want to select elements with a single class you do:

```
$('.foo')
```

If you want to select elements with multiple classes, you do:

```
$('.foo.bar')
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. 
$(".zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1.Napa1-topnav.zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3").removeAttr("style");

Comment: It *should* work. Try to see if the selector returns the element you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`.zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1.Napa1-topnav.zz1_TopNavigationMenu_whatever`

Will get you elements that have all 3 of those classes. The wildcard doesnt work - there is no facility for this using CSS selectors. I would add a class of something like: `zz1_TopNavigationMenu` and then anything that was also `zz1_TopNavigationMenu_whatever` would get thsi grouping class. OR if possible you could use ID's or elements to get them all. For instance if its a menu id expect them all to be `li` elements so you could use: `.zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1.Napa1-topnav li` or something similar.

Take a look at the [docs on css selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for use with jQuery.